# How to have a gradient background under edge of Line Chart?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, monodevelop

I am using UltimateXF dependency in xamarin form for displaying chart. I am using one of chart is Line Chart, i want to show graident color below edge of line chart not to fill whole background.
I want like this.
[The White and blue gradient](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WCkTb.png)

Comment: looks like its already supported https://github.com/bulubuloa/Ultimate-Xamarin-Forms-KIT, readme, scroll down

Comment: This Update is not supported in recent version of ultimateXF. When new version is coming any idea?